# NodeJS/Express4 endpoint generating corrupt xlsx file

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am trying to create an endpoint using NodeJS/express 4 that generates and send to the user a xlsx file.

To create the xlsx file I am using the `node-xlsx` library.

```
var xlsx = require('node-xlsx');
var buffer = xlsx.build([{
  name: pasta,
  data: data
}]);
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + pasta + ".xlsx");
res.write(buffer, 'binary');
return res.end();
```

And I am trying to download this file through an Angular app.

```
$http.post('https://endpoint/v1/' + folderName + '/reportExcel', {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
  })
  .success(function(response) {
      var blob = new Blob([response], {
        type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
      });
      var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      $window.open(objectUrl);
```

However, the file that is being downloaded is broken, so I can not open it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Im having a similiar problem...

Comment: @MikeFielden see my answer below

Answer (score 5):

Could it because you are using connect-livereload plugin? The plugin seems cause corrupted binary files being transferred. I've encountered the same, and solved it by adding 'ignore' when initiate connect-livereload plugin.

```
app.use(require('connect-livereload')({
    ignore:['.xls', '.xlsx']
}));
```

See this post for detail: https://github.com/intesso/connect-livereload/issues/39

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks!

Comment: Thank youuuuuuu!
I spend 8 hours of my time and if I did not see that I would spend more

Answer (score 0):

I posted an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41103999/1623249

Basically, you need to get the buffer from `node-xlsx`, convert it to `base64` and then decode it in the client.